# Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support

Tags: tensorflow, linux-kernel, numa

I have Jetson TX2, python 2.7, Tensorflow 1.5, CUDA 9.0

Tensorflow seems to be working but everytime, I run the program, I get this warning:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(y,feed_dict))
```

...

```
2018-08-07 18:07:53.200320: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:881] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/numa_node Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.

2018-08-07 18:07:53.200427: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties:

name: NVIDIA Tegra X2
major: 6 
minor: 2 
memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3005

pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0

totalMemory: 7.66GiB 
freeMemory: 1.79GiB

2018-08-07 18:07:53.200474: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X2, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 6.2)

2018-08-07 18:07:53.878574: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:859] Could not identify NUMA node of /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
```

Should I be worried? Or is it something negligible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem for you, since you don't need NUMA support for this board (it has only one memory controller, so memory accesses are uniform).

Also, I found [this post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027507/jetson-tx2/numa-error-running-tensorflow-on-jetson-tx2/) on nvidia forum that seems to confirm this.